# autoclick link with javascript without id/class

Tags: javascript, click, location

got this example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function init(){
        var linkPage = document.getElementById('linkid').href;
        window.location.href = linkPage;
    }
    onload=init;
</script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="someplace.html" id="linkid">GO HERE</a>

</body>
</html>
```

this script clicks the link "GO HERE". (works perfect)

but in my example i got no class or id in the link.

```
<a href="someplace_with_session.php&c=ToMNi1ffNs4qf55cSmaisSvv3h8NqUliyO&o=16cb29acefffyccc83bbd8e&r=338a8d7492839096df1dd">LINK NAME</a>
```

is only thing that never change is the name of the link ("LINK NAME")

is it possible to search for "LINK NAME" and then click it like the working script above?

or something that will do what i need :D

Comment: Why can't you give it an id?  That's what they are for.

Comment: @Dennis just need the code for greasemonkey! can't add an id because the website is not mine :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JS has no way to search for a node by text contents (that I know of).

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('a'), function (elem) {
    if (elem.innerHTML.indexOf('LINK NAME') > -1) {
        window.location = elem.href;
    }
});
```

Comment: your code works also perfect.. just one question: it needs around 1 sec when the link gets "clicked". do you think there is an faster method?

Comment: Is there a more specific place to search for your `a` instead of the entire document?

Comment: Worth noting: Not all browsers in significant use have `Array.prototype.forEach`, you may need a shim for some. (I'm looking at *you*, Microsoft.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I like to pretend that everyone who uses IE at least uses IE9

Comment: @ExplosionPills: In non-"compatibility" mode. Ah, if only 'twere so. The heart can only aspire... But actually, the OP said something about GreaseMonkey, so you're all set.

Comment: i got a <ul class="navwrap"><li class="navitem"><a ..>LINK TEXT</a></li></ul> arround the link. but there are more <li class="navitem"> links in the navwrap. don't know if its important.

Comment: @bernte change `getElementsByTagName('a')` to `querySelectorAll('.navwrap a')`

Comment: mhh.. i think its the same also 1 second

Comment: @bernte your document must be huge .. is there an ID parent that is close to the `.navwrap` element?

Comment: the class navwrap is all i found.. :(

Comment: @bernte you can always ask another question on this website

Comment: @bernte I ran my same code on one of the stackoverflow pages and it ran instantaneously against about 250 links.  Maybe the delay is something else

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the links in the document and check the text:

```
for(var i = 0, len = document.links.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    if(document.links[i].textContent === "LINK TEXT") {
        document.links[i].click();
    }
}
```

Comment: dennis your code works perfect.. just one question: it needs around 1 sec when the link gets "clicked". do you think there is an faster method? :D

Comment: Note that `textContent` isn't necessarily reliable cross-browser (fall back on `innerText`), and one could argue that `document.getElementsByTagName('a')` is more well-documented than `document.links`. But fundamentally, this is the right answer.

Comment: Not without knowing more about the document.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder OP said it was for greasemonkey so I figured it was okay.  Someone wanting to apply it to a different scenario may need that note, though.  `document.links` is specified in DOM Level 2 and shorter than gEBTN so I don't feel bad about that one either.

Comment: @Dennis: Ah, good point! He/she *did* mention GreaseMonkey... (Wow, `links` is in DOM2? I need to re-read that... I'm rubbish on my shortcut properties...)

Comment: i got a <ul class="navwrap"><li class="navitem"><a ..>LINK TEXT</a></li></ul> arround the link. but there are more <li class="navitem"> links in the navwrap. don't know if its important.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just use the following bit, which uses jquery selection.

```
var link = $("a:contains('LINK TEXT')"); //get the a
var click = document.createEvent("Event"); //create event
click.initEvent("click", true, true);
link.dispatchEvent(click); // make it happen
```

Comment: The OP has said nothing about jQuery. Please don't post jQuery-only answers to non-jQuery questions.

Comment: dude, instead of straight trolling, why not offer any real worth to the post? @T.J.Crowder.

Comment: @ Todd: ***Dude***, asking that people actually answer the question as asked is not trolling. (I've posted ***4,500+*** answers, hardly troll-like behavior.) I've been around this block. jQuery answers to non-jQuery questions are not cool. Look for it on meta. Meanwhile, there's a perfectly good answer to this question already, so there was no reason for me to post one.

Comment: fair enough. Can I borrow some silvadene for that burn? @t.j. Crowder